Geometric stability conditions on calabi-yau's fibred over Fano always identical to geometric stability conditions on Fano
I apologize in advance for the long title. This question is motivated primarily by [2], with the explicit example of $\mathbb{P}^2$ and $\omega_{\mathbb{P}^2}$ computed in [3] and [1], respectively.
Let $Z$ be a smooth Fano variety which admits a full exceptional collection and satisfies $\dim K(Z) \otimes \mathbb{C} = \dim Z + 1$. Let $\omega_Z$ denote the quasi-projective variety obtained as the total space of the canonical bundle of $Z$, and $\mathcal{D}_{0, Z}$ the full subcategory of $D^\flat(\operatorname{Coh}(\omega_Z))$ consisting of objects whose cohomology sheaves are supported on the zero section $Z \subset \omega_Z$.
By a geometric stability condition, I mean any Bridgeland stability condition $\sigma = (Z, \mathcal{P})$ such that, up to the $\widetilde{\operatorname{GL}^+(2, \mathbb{R})}$-action, all skyscraper sheaves $k(x)$ are stable of phase 1 (though for the category $\mathcal{D}_{0, Z}$, it is important to restrict this to $x \in Z$). Refer to the set of all such stability conditions as the geometric chamber. It was shown in [1] and [3] that when we take $Z = \mathbb{P}^2$, the geometric chamber of $D^\flat(\mathbb{P}^2)$ and $\mathcal{D}_{0, \mathbb{P}^2}$ are identical (due to the works of Drezet and Le Potier in classifying the Chern characters of Gieseker-stable sheaves on $\mathbb{P}^2$). While the boundary of the geometric chamber and chamber-decomposition are vastly different for $\mathbb{P}^2$ and $\omega_{\mathbb{P}^2}$, is it reasonable to expect in general that the geometric chamber for $D^\flat(Z)$ and $\mathcal{D}_{0, Z}$ are the same for any general smooth Fano $Z$ (satisfying the initial assumptions)?

[1] Arend Bayer and Emanuele Macrì, The Space of Stability Conditions on the Local Projective Plane, Duke Math. J.
160 (2011), no. 2, 263–322, DOI 10.1215/00127094-1444249
[2] Tom Bridgeland, T-structures on some local Calabi–Yau varieties, Journal of Algebra 289 (2005), no. 2, 453-483,
DOI https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2005.03.016.
[3] Chunyi Li, The Space of Stability Conditions on the Projective Plane, Selecta Mathematica 23 (2017), 2927–2945,
DOI https://doi.org/10.1007/s00029-017-0352-4.
